# How to mark myself as the opposite of a LinkedIn LION to discourage invitations from them?

Tags: linkedin

I don't want to receive invitations from [LinkedIn LIONs](https://topdogsocialmedia.com/why-i-dont-connect-with-lions-on-linkedin/):

> A LION is defined as a LinkedIn Open Networker. Basically a LION is someone who will accept a connection request from everyone and anyone who sends them one.

[LinkedIn LIONs](https://topdogsocialmedia.com/why-i-dont-connect-with-lions-on-linkedin/) like to mark themselves with their "LION" status:

> LIONs are easy to identify, as they will often display this in their profile in a number of places including their name field, headline and summary section.

I'm assuming they do this to attract invitations from eachother.  **Is there a comparable label I can use to mark myself as the opposite**, to repel invitations from LIONs?  ("The opposite" meaning I don't want to hear from you unless you're interested in working together soon, or we've worked together in the past.)

Comment: For what purpose you want to mark yourself as such? In what context or for what purpose?... you could say !LION (joking haha)... anyways, how do you know "they like to mark themselves" that way? Please clarify

Comment: You can be an Anti-LION.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about web app usage.

Comment: @DJClayworth yeah, a web app that helps people build their professional profile and contact other professionals (sound like Navigating the workplace to me)... still, the question need clarification so a proper edit can be done to reveal the on-topic question that lies there

Comment: You can be a NIOL - Not Interested in Opportunist Links.

Comment: The LinkedIn LIONs link appears to be broken (or possibly blocked by corporate firewall). For those of us who don't know, can you define a LinkedIn LION?

Comment: @Maybe_Factor Thanks for pointing that out. It does seem like you are blocked by a firewall. I have incorporated the definition from the article directly into the post.

Answer (score 6):

> I don't want to receive invitations from LinkedIn LIONs.

Well, I don't think you can *stop* people from sending invitations to you on LinkedIn.

However, what you *can* do is **don't accept such invitations**.

LinkedIn provides the option to reply to people even though you are not connected with them, without having to accept the invitation. That way you may probe for their real intentions before deciding to accept.

Comment: I haven't used it for a while, but I seem to recall that you could mark invites from people whom you don't know as spam. I always did so, in the hopes that LinkedIn would ban them. Apparently I was being naive

Answer (score 6):

> I don't want to receive invitations from LinkedIn LIONs.

There are a number of approaches to achieve this:

#### 1.  Prevent receiving invitations from anyone

Since LinkedIn doesn't provide any way to distinguish Lions from <s>other animals</s> non-Lions, err on the side of safety and assume that *everyone* is a Lion. You can do the following:

1. Me → Settings & Privacy  → Privacy → Sync contacts → (change) → Contacts → (remove all)
2. Me → Settings & Privacy → Communications → Preferences → Who can send you invitations → Only people who appear in your “Imported Contacts” list

   Step 1 cleans up all your "imported contacts" while Step 2 allows invitations only from people in your "imported contacts", which is now empty.

#### 2. Suggest an improvement

Help Center → LinkedIn Help Forum → Contact us → Suggest an improvement

Describe your problem there and politely request them for the following features:

- Allow users to be marked as Lions, either by themselves or using a mechanism similar to "endorsements" (For example, 42 users have endorsed John Doe as a Lion).
- Additional option in Step 2 above: "Only non-Lions".

> Is there a comparable way I can mark myself as the opposite?

As stated above, Linked doesn't (presently) distinguish Lions from non-Lions. However, after they implement the improvement suggested above in approach 2, it should be fairly straightforward to mark yourself a non-Lion.

---

*Note*: The information described above is accurate as of 10 August 2018, and may become outdated in future.